# Criar classes e funções em c++

Tags: c++, funções, classes

Alguém pode dar um exemplo de como criar o main, o .h e o .cpp em c++? E também liga-las todas. Por exemplo ter uma função que recebe de um input um valor a, ter outra classe que recebe de input um b e numa classe à parte fazer a soma e retornar para o main. Sou nova nesta linguagem.

Comment: Tem como colocar na pergunta o código que tentou fazer? Assim conseguiremos ver melhor em quais partes está com dificuldade. Já adianto que uma resposta do tipo "não sei começar" é um bom sinal que você deve revisar o básico antes de tentar algo como o que está fazendo. Talvez revisar os conteúdos de construção de algoritmos e reler o material sobre a sintaxe do C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include padrão para o uso da linguagem

```
#include <iostream>
```

using padrão para o uso da linguagem

```
using namespace std;
```

Criando uma classe `Acampamentos`

```
class Acampamentos{
public:
    int idade;
    string nome;
    char equipe;

    Acampamentos();
    void imprimir();
    void separarGrupo();
};
```

Formato padrão do construtor

```
Acampamentos::Acampamentos(){

    idade =0;
    nome = " ";
    equipe = ' ';
}
```

Criando uma função `imprimir()` somente para imprimir os atributos da classe no console

```
void Acampamentos::imprimir(){
    cout << "Idade .: " << idade << endl;
    cout << "Nome ..: " << nome << endl;
    cout << "Equipe : " << equipe << endl;
}
```

Forma de imprimir no console 
`cout << "String desejada" <<` Concatena com a atributo desejado `<< endl` 
endl pula linha ao final da escrita no console (End Line)

Criando uma função seperarGrupo aonde define a equipe por idade

```
void Acampamentos::separarGrupo(){

    if(idade >=6 && idade <= 10){
        equipe = 'A';
    }

    if(idade > 10 && idade <= 20){
        equipe = 'B';
    }

    if(idade >20){
        equipe = 'C';
    }
}
```

Criando a main

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Acampamentos A;

    cout << "Escreva o nome : ";
    cin >> A.nome;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Digite a idade :";
    cin >> A.idade;
    cout << endl;
    system("cls");
    A.imprimir();
    system("cls");
    A.separarGrupo();
    A.imprimir();
    return 0;
}
```

Para receber um input e atribuir em outra variável `cin >> Atributo desejado` . Caso esteja dentro de uma classe usa-se a instancia `Instancia.atributo_desejado`